# Select field of record contains max of another field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.x

I want to select a field of a record that contains max value of a filed in grouped items.
Assume that these are my table and content;

```
id    |     name     |   surname   |      age

1          ahmet           adal1            25
2          mehmet          mdal2            23
3          ahmet           adal3            27
4          ahmet           adal4            22
5          mehmet          mdal5            28
```

I want to group all records by name and select surname of the record that contains max age.

I should get as result;

```
adal3
mdal5
```

here is a query that I want to run;

```
select p.surname 
from person p
group by name
having max(age)
```

I know this is not working and having expression must be boolean. I gave this just to explain myself better.

Is there a way to get what I want with sql, especially PostgreSQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has the syntax `distinct on` that does this:

```
select distinct on (name) p.surname 
from person p
order by name, age desc
```